# ASP.NET MVC3 Server-Side Validations and Partial View forms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-partialview

So... I got this one conundrum. My model is a 'User' that has about 15 different fields (including a few Bool fields, and a Password field). For the sake of convenience, I can't  have one single big form for it and instead, I came up with the idea to make a tabbed layout of several forms that map to several different 'Sub Models' (I guess one might call them ViewModels) that post to specific Methods in the User controller. The user controller then validates the ViewModels and if they pass, it updates the original User.

The problem is with what happens if the validation fails - I need to find a way to re-display the full tabbed layout for User (with 4 forms in 4 tabs, mapping to 4 Models), and include the changes made by user that didn't pass validations. The problem is, depending on which of the 4 forms were edited, the 'returning' object is one of 4 types, so the other 3 forms (in different tabs) would have to be populated by existing user data as they were before submit was pressed.

I'm probably just not seeing the forest for the trees, but can someone suggest an approach to this type of a problem?

EDIT: To add more information - the problem is - if the server side validation fails, I need to re-render the edit forms in the tabbed layout, with a validation error message. I could easily do this by truncating the user input and re-loading the original 'User' data, but obviously, I'd want to maintain the input.

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to save the input in the forms on a validation failure.  Your best bet, imo, is to do all the validation client side.  That will give all the forms a smooth, consistent feel.  

Anything that can't be validated client side, I would move to it's own view and handle it separately.

Then, for your wonderful users that figure out how to bypass your client side validation, but fail the server side check, well, they'll just have to deal with re typing their input.

Comment: @Forty-Two - if I had the option to do it that way, I would have. Think of 'Old Password' verification in the Password Change form, is it wise doing client-side validation for that?